# Swift UIView Memory Usage & Dealing With Many Subviews

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a Word Search app, where I display a large 14x14 grid of letters. Right now, I display each letter using its own `UILabel` as such:

```
for _ in 0..<14 {
  for _ in 0..<14 {
    let letterLabel = UILabel()
    letterLabel.text = randomLetter()
    addSubview(letterLabel)
  }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if I would be better off structuring my code as such:

```
let lettersLabel = UILabel()
for _ in 0..<14 {
  for _ in 0..<14 {
    letterLabel.text += randomLetter() + " "
  }
  letterLabel.text += "\n"
}
addSubview(letterLabel)
```

My theory is that this will reduce my app's memory footprint, although I can't find any documentation about exactly how much memory each `UILabel` will take up.

But, I'm wondering, **how much memory would the latter approach actually save me? And which approach is standard/preferred in iOS development?** Or, is there a third approach I haven't thought of?

I feel that the latter approach is better from a performance standpoint, but would greatly complicate the code when it comes to spacing the letters evenly across the screen and determining which letter is tapped.

(Note: This question dramatically simplifies my actual code to highlight the problem area)

Comment: Obviously it will reduce your memory if you use less number of views. And in this case by a lot because you are using one label instead of 14*14.

Comment: A third approach is to directly draw text in a custom `UIView`, which gives you a lot of freedom as to where each letter is.

Comment: You could use CALayers to display your text, it's way cheaper than UIView's or UILabel's, if you don't need to be able to click on them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I wasn't aware of those options. However, I do need to be able to click on the UILabels. I could probably still do this one with only one view by looking at the screen coordinates of the tap though. Are there any existing code samples explaining how to draw text on a custom view?

Comment: What about collectionView?

Comment: Will collection view be more memory-efficient or just simplify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to know which letter is tapped, I would recommend using a collection view. Here is a sample implementation:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    //Here I am generating an array of 14*14 strings since I don't have access to the randomLetter() function
    let elements = (0..<(14 * 14)).map { String($0) }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.label = UILabel(frame: cell.bounds)
        cell.label.text = elements[indexPath.row] //In your case you would use: cell.label.text = randomLetter()
        cell.label.font = UIFont(name: "helvetica", size: 10)
        cell.label.textAlignment = .center
        cell.addSubview(cell.label)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width/14, height: self.view.frame.size.width/14)
        return size
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        print(String(describing: cell.label.text))
    }
}
```

Where `CollectionViewCell` is a custom `UICollectionViewCell`defined as follows:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var label: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Why is this more memory-efficient than just using `UILabel` directly? It seems like the same number of `UILabel`s will be instantiated but now there's additional overhead from all the `UICollectionViewCell`s.